# SpeckPaypal ZF2 How to edit the CURRENCY CODE?

Tags: php, paypal, zend-framework2

i 've succed in installing the mod SpeckPaypal for ZF2 , and i can make some tests , but i 'm facing 2 problems here:
1 - i can't change the  CURRENCY CODE from USD to EUR !!
2 - i can't see the money going to the facilitator instead of seeing that the credit of the bayer is changing ?

i tried to change the value in this file :

```
SpeckPaypal/src/SpeckPaypal/Request/DoCapture.php
protected $currencyCode = 'USD'; // to 'EUR' but it doesn't work
```

plz any idea is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found the solution , is to edit the

```
protected $currencyCode = 'USD'; // to 'EUR' 
in the class \SpeckPaypal\Element\PaymentDetails.php
```

Hope it helps.